# Android Spinner on Item Selected Is Not Working?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

So guys i am trying to implement the **OnItemSelectedListener** to my spinner.
The data is retrived from the firebase and added to the arraylist and that array list i added to the adatper

```
//spinner stufff
//variables:

    Spinner schoolNamesSpinner;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    ArrayList<String> instituteNames;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(studentsLogIn.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, instituteNames);

        schoolNamesSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        **// populating selector;**

        populatingSelecto();
```

**populating the spinner**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oRq3.png)

```
**// populating selector**

private void populatingSelecto() {

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {

                for (DataSnapshot ids : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    uniqIds.add(ids.getKey());

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < uniqIds.size(); i++) {
                    databaseReference.child(uniqIds.get(i)).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                String name = snapshot.child("INSTITUTE").child("institutionName").
                                        getValue().toString();

                                instituteNames.add(name);


                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                }

            } else {
                dialogboxMeathod(studentsLogIn.this, "No Institutes on the Record");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });


}
```

So, on item selected am trying to show the text of the item selected but its not working

```
    schoolNamesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(studentsLogIn.this, instituteNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**i had to notify the adapter just after adding stuff**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < uniqIds.size(); i++) {
            databaseReference.child(uniqIds.get(i)).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        String name = snapshot.child("INSTITUTE").child("institutionName").getValue().toString();
                        instituteNames.add(name);
                        // here i have to add the adapter.notifydatachanged
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You havent initialise your spinner:

```
    Spinner schoolNamesSpinner;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    ArrayList<String> instituteNames;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
   schoolNamesSpinner=findViewById(R.id.your_spinner_id);//this line
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(studentsLogIn.this,
   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, instituteNames);

      schoolNamesSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

**// populating selector;**

     populatingSelecto();


   schoolNamesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(studentsLogIn.this, instituteNames.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//use getItemAtPosition
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
```

Comment: schoolNamesSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner_students_login);                                                      // i did intitalize it but forgot to paste the code

Comment: check my updated answer InshaAllah this time it will work.

Comment: Check your logcat if your item is getting clicked or not.Use Log.d function in your onItemSelected to check whether the your items are getting selected or not i.e the problem is with toast or with selection itself.

Comment: Bhai jaan when i retreive data from the firebase it is not working The data is being showed but onitem selector is not working so i commented out  the populating selector and  added stuff directly to test   like                             
               institutename.add("A") . then the on item selector is working

Comment: I thought the problem was with selection good to see you got the solution.